# How do I use gstreamer to encode an ffv1 file?

Tags: gstreamer

I'd like to encode a video with gstreamer to an FFV1 (ffmpeg's lossless video format) file.  However, I cannot work out what type of mux'ing to use.  If I run this:

gst-launch videotestsrc ! ffenc_ffv1 ! filesink location="test.ffv1"

Then the thing runs OK, but the resulting file doesn't appear to be a valid video file.  When creating theora videos, I've previously written "theora ! oggmux ! filesink" in the pipeline, and this works.  However, oggmux doesn't work here.  What type of transport stream should I be using here, and what is the correct gst-launch fudge to use?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be supported in the version I have installed. You can check it for your version by saving the output of `gst-xmlinspect` to a file and searching for `video/x-ffv` in this file. The elements where this mime type is mentioned are:

- avidemux
- ogmvideoparse
- ffdec_ffv1
- ffenc_ffv1

So it seems this is supported by the avi demuxer but not by any muxer.

PS: The mime type can be found with `gst-inspect ffenc_ffv1`.